# Eclipse RCP Preference Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

### Question

Is it possible to create a second Preference Dialog that can take some `PreferencePage`, much like the standard eclipse Preference (Eclipse > Preferences or Window > Preferences)?

### Current Approach

My solution so far was to create my own `PreferenceEditorDialog` by extend `Dialog` and implementing my own Preference Dialog style layout.

```
/**
 * A preference dialog is a hierarchical presentation of preference pages. Each
 * page is represented by a node in the tree shown on the left hand side of the
 * dialog; when a node is selected, the corresponding page is shown on the right
 * hand side.
 */
public class PreferenceEditorDialog extends Dialog implements IPageChangeProvider {

}
```

I would much rather reuse an eclipse implementation as I don't have to maintain the code myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PreferenceDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/PreferenceDialog.html) is what you are looking for.